# Django ignore character in url parameter

Tags: django, django-urls

Hi I have a url pattern like so:

```
url(
    r'^project_info/(?P<product>\w+)/$',
    'tool.views.ProjectInfo',
    name='project_info'
),
```

this works fine for normal strings, but if I want to capture something like 'my-product' it fails.

I have tried escaping the dash like so:

```
url(
    r'^project_info/(?P<product>\-\w+)/$',
    'tool.views.ProjectInfo',
    name='project_info'
),
```

but no joy.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work for you

```
url(
    r'^project_info/(?P<product>[-\w]+)/$',
    'tool.views.ProjectInfo',
    name='project_info'
),
```